# why do these two functions not return in same form

Tags: python

For instance,

```
def T(x):
for i in range(1,len(x)-1):
        x[i]+=x[i-1]+2

def f(x):
    x=x+2
    return x

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
;T(x)
;print(x)
[1, 5, 10, 16, 5]
```

the variable x changes in this case but,

```
x=3
;f(x)
;print(x)
x=3
```

x does not change in this case.

why is this happening?

Comment: Lists are mutable, ints are not.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, mutable object is passed as reference while immutable ones are passed by values.

To get same result as (1):

```
x = 3
x = f(x)
print(x)
```

You can check this [web](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) for more info on this.